# I want to save UIImage instead of nil value on parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I am implementing saving post part, the post contains user profile Picture when it is saved for showing on main page. but there would be a user who hasn't profile picture. I tried this code, it occurs error.

```
if let profilePicture = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profile_picture") {
    post["profile_picture"] = profilePicture
} else {
    post["profile_picture"] = UIImage(named: "AvatarPlaceholder" )
}
post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( isSucessful: Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.alert("success", message : "your post has been uploaded")
    } else {
        self.alert("Error", message : (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
```

if user has profile photo, it will be fine. but if not, that is the problem.

I have Avatarplaceholder jpeg file in assets.

**my questions are.....**

how can I upload my avatarplaceHolder ?

or is there better way to cover nil value?,

actually I don't want to waste my cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to wrap you UIImage into a PFFile as follows:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "AvatarPlaceholder")!, 0.5)!
let profileImageFile = PFFile(name: "profileImage", data: imageData)
post["profile_picture"] = profileImageFile
```

Comment: it was PNG,  and I changed your code to                                                       let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "AvatarPlaceholder")!)
                let profileImageFile = PFFile(name: "profileImage.png", data: imageData!)
                post["profile_picture"] = profileImageFile
it's not working. Do you see why?

Comment: 2015-10-12 19:51:59.834 bany[4650:1872022] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

Comment: Debug it and check what value is nil. Maybe your asset is not named "AvatarPlaceholder".

Comment: Then I gotta know how to debug it, and AvatarPlaceholder is right name of it.  Thanks man!